# Two oracle databases on one IP

Tags: oracle, listener, tns

What I have:
1) Oracle 11R1 services on Local system
2) Oracle 12c services on other account

TNS listener run from  oracle 11R1 (but also I've create one for 12c)

As a first solution I try

```
A12c =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.1.1.1)(PORT = 1531))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = A12c.1.1.1)
    )
  )


B11R1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.1.1.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = B11R1)
    )
  )


LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.1.1.1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.1.1.1)(PORT = 1531))
    )
  )
```

With this configuration I could connect to 11r1 (also on 1531 port !) but nt to 12c. When I setup two listener situation was same. When I run with 12c listener I could not connect to any databases.

Will be grateful for any suggestions.
Thank you

Comment: `(SERVICE_NAME = A12c.1.1.1)` is not correct most likely

Comment: but this is done by oracle instalation, look like SID.domain.com (here I put 1.1.1 to show that this is connected with part of IP, but I do not have this domain, in 11r1 SID have other form under instalation). Should I change this (also test with A12c).

Comment: When I leave in tns and listener files ony port 1531, start listener service from 12c I've got this error (TNS_PATH is set !) 

LSNRCTL STATUS

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 15-JUL-2016 15:52
:06

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error

Comment: `domain.com` would equate to a full IP address for one so you would need an extra `.1` in that case, but just A12c should also work. Can you connect to 12c now? Have you ever been able to connect to it? Pretty sure you need individual listener services since they are different Oracle homes so include only the info for each specific home in each listener.ora file.

Comment: I think SID is OK, yes this is true. I try to use oracle configurator, create new listener for 12c and still nothing In OD Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
X.X.X.X:1522:SID
But I have this SID in configuration (I think that I could have number inside sid eg. XX12XX not at the beginning).